# How to best pull the list of users who are in multiple fields/columns?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to pull the list of users (with user_id being the related variable) and list them so we can see which users satisfy the condition of each field/column.

There are two tables in concern:

Table_A (stores the location of the users)
Table_B (stores the characteristics of the users)

I want to join these two tables using the related variable **user_id** to pull where each of these users are also present in each columns/fields under the two tables.

Basically, I want the output to have a value of 1 if the user_id is present in the field (column) and 0 if the user_id is not present in the field (column).

[How I want the data output to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te3Db.png)

I tried concatenating the column outputs per user but it became very messy and the user_id values were duplicated - I want to show unique user_id in rows.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I've also removed the conflicting tags; SQL Server and MySQL are *very* different products. Please only tag the (R)DBMS you are really using. As you don't mention "dataminer" in  the question at all, and [[tag:dataminer]] has no usage guidance, I've removed that tag too. If you are asking about dataminer (whatever that is), then incldue details on how it's related to the question in your [edit].

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.